# Unable to understand hash partitioning in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a dummy table and I created hash partitions on it like

```
create table hash_test(cat int) partition by hash(cat);
create table h0 partition of hash_test for values with (modulus 2, remainder 0);
create table h1 partition of hash_test for values with (modulus 2, remainder 1);
```

and I add a few records in there.

```
insert into hash_test values(0);
insert into hash_test values(1);
and so on....
```

When I see the two partitions I get the following results

```
postgres=# select * from h0;
 cat 
-----
   0
   1
   2
(3 rows)

postgres=# select * from h1;
 cat 
-----
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
  10
(8 rows)
```

I understood hash partitioning as, All the rows in which cat modulo 2 == 0 will go into partition h0, h1 otherwise.
The results are not at all consistent with my understanding. Can anybody please help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: The HASH of the value is used in the modulus and remainder operation not the value itself. Fields with a small number of possible values are not good candidates for use in hash partitioning.

Comment: Understood. Thanks @Brian